# Identifying a key in one dict, and using it to modify values of another dict

Tags: python, dictionary

For a text-based RPG I'm creating, I have dictionaries outlining various in-game religions, races, etc. Some values of these religions include buffs for player's stats, e.g.:

```
religion_Dict = {'Way of the White': {'buffs': {'intelligence': 5, 'defense': 3},
                                     'abilities': [...],
                                     'description': '...'}}
```

My question comes along when trying to apply a religion's stat buffs to a player's stats. If I have a player class that looks something like:

```
class Player(object)    
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.religion = None
        self.stats = {'intelligence': 10, 'defense': 8}
```

Now, let's say the player joins the religion `Way of the White`, how do I go about identifying the keys `intelligence` and `defense` and their respective values -- inside of the dictionary `religion_dict` -- and apply them onto the values of the player's `stats` dictionary?

I know I can pull the key names with `religion_Dict.keys()` or a basic for loop, but how can I use that to correctly modify the corresponding player stat values?

I'm sure I'm just missing a basic concept. In any case, thanks to anyone willing to help answer this simple question! I appreciate it!

Comment: Why would use you use .keys when you can do a lookup using the key?

Comment: Do you want to add the buffs from the religion to the player stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of how you would go about this:

```
religion_Dict = {'Way of the White': {'buffs': {'intelligence': 5, 'defense': 3},
                                     'abilities': [...],
                                     'description': '...'}}
buffs = religion_Dict['Way of the White']['buffs']

for key in buffs:
    player.stats[key] = player.stats.get(key,0) + buffs[key]
```

Of course, you should wrap this logic in a method in your Player class, but the logic above is what you are looking for. Notice the `.get` method takes a second argument which is a default value it returns if there is no key value. Thus, this line will add 1 to whatever stat is there, and if it doesn't exist, it adds 1 to 0.

Answer (score 1):

This adds a method to `Player` that assigns the values from your dictionary to player stats.  It uses `get` to ensure that the value is in the dictionary and that it contains the field `buffs`.  If so, it gets the values for `intelligence` and `defense` and adds them to the player's stats.

```
class Player(object)    
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.religion = None
        self.stats = {'intelligence': 10, 'defense': 8}

    def join_religion(religion):
        stats = religion_dict.get(religion)
        if stats and 'buffs' in stats:
            self.intelligence += stats['buffs'].get('intelligence', 0)
            self.defense += stats['buffs'].get('defense', 0)

p = Player()
p.join_religion('Way of the White')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.stats = religion_Dict['Way of the White']['buffs']
```